# Why nm shows no symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6?

Tags: linux, shared-library, symbol-table, nm

I expected to see number of symbols in the **libc.so.6** file including **printf**.  I used the **nm** tool to find them, however it says there is no symbol in libc.so.6.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's probably got its regular symbols stripped and what's left is its dynamic symbols, which you can get with `nm -D`.

Answer (score 17):

@PSkocik answered this. I just want to add more detail. There are two kinds of symbol sections in ELF: `.symtab` and `.dynsym` (see the [Linux Standard Base Core Specification, a.k.a. LSB_5.0.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.pdf), for details). `.symtab` is for the linking step of the shared lib itself. Once linking is finished, the `.symtab` section is not needed anymore. The `.dynsym` section contains important symbols that are supposed to be searched by the dynamic linker at run time. `nm` by default only dumps symbols in the `.symtab` section.

[LSB_5.0.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.pdf) Section 10.2.2.1, “ELF Section Types”, says a conforming shared lib should have either `.symtab` or `.dynsym` but not both. As part of the ABI library, libc is stripped out of the `.symtab` to be spec conforming.

Answer (score 0):

Find out if it is a shared object, or, a regular ASCII file.  If it is a shared object you should see "ELF 32-bit LSB shared object,"

```
file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: `libc.so.6` is oviously a shared object.

Comment: I never assume in a Linux environment.  Considering someone could have touched the root directories.  Yes, by name it is obviously a share object.  And, it doesn't hurt to verify; when you are not getting the expected output.